# Тренируюсь на задачах, но проверяющая программа не засчитывает ответ

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Яша плавал в бассейне размером N×M метров и устал. В этот момент он
>   обнаружил, что находится на расстоянии x метров от одного из длинных
>   бортиков (не обязательно от ближайшего) и y метров от одного из
>   коротких бортиков. Какое минимальное расстояние должен проплыть Яша,
>   чтобы выбраться из бассейна на бортик?
>
> Входные данные:
>
> Программа получает на вход целые числа
>
> Программа должна вывести число метров, которое нужно проплыть Яше до бортика.

Мой код:

```
N = int(input())
M = int(input())
x = int(input())
y = int(input())

n = N - x
m = M - y

if (n <= x) and (n <= y) and (n <= m):
    print(n)

if (x <= n) and (x <= y) and (x <= m):
    print(x)

if (m <= x) and (m <= y) and (m <= y):
    print(m)

if (y <= x) and (y <= n) and (y <= m):
    print(y)
```

Comment: версия языка: 3

Comment: и еще: вполне допускается другое решение задачи, но я решил лезть через дебри

Comment: Даже начинающий питонист должен уметь писать краткие заголовки по существу. Минус один.

Comment: Погуглите "pythontutor решения" задача оттуда.

Comment: @jfkvy234, пожалуйста, в следующий раз форматируйте свой код

Comment: Хорошо, учту все комментарии

Answer (score 2):

На pythontutor проверил, все работает (задача оттуда)

```py
N = int(input())
M = int(input())
x = int(input())
y = int(input())

length = max(N, M)
width = min(N, M)

short_length = min(width - x, width - (width - x))
short_width = min(length - y, length - (length - y))

response = min(short_length, short_width)
print(response)
```

> Для любителей поплотнее )))

```py
N, M, x, y = [int(input()) for _ in range(4)]

print(
    min(
        min(max(N, M) - y, max(N, M) - (max(N, M) - y)),
        min(min(N, M) - x, min(N, M) - (min(N, M) - x))
    )
)
```

[image: Решение разработчиков]

Comment: Спасибо, но я сделал немного по-другому

Comment: n = int(input())
m = int(input())
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
if n>m: n,m = m,n
print(min(x, y, n-x, m-y))

Answer (score 0):

`NxM` может быть `20x10` и `10x20` . нужно поменять `N` и `M` местами если `N>M`, чтоб x сравнивался с коротким расстоянием.

```
if N>M: N,M = M,N
```

Comment: я думал об этом, но не сделал, потому что в IDE все  и так работало. Сейчас попробую сдать на проверку, может получится. Спасибо

Comment: не сработало...

Comment: смотри ещё, может ошибки есть

Comment: Именно. Просмотрел первую подсказку, первым делом высветилось то, что подсказали Вы

Comment: вообщем, ищу ошибки

Comment: а будет ли проще сделать через функцию максимума и минимума?

Comment: @jfkvy234 намного